# Run vba on Microsoft Excel 2019 on Catalina

Tags: excel, vba, macos, macos-catalina

I want to run the system command directly from Microsoft Excel using:

```
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
#Else
        Private Declare Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
#End If

system ("echo hello")
```

But I get errors on that

> Run-Time error '453': File not found: ibc.dylib

I try to use the full path and again

> Run-Time error '453': File not found: /usr/lib/libc.dylib

I know there was some sandbox error in the past :(

Do I do something rung here or it's the Catalina sandbox?

Are there is any other working method for running a normal python/bash script from VBA?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Run-Time error '453': File not found: /usr/lib/libc.dylib

Comment: As far as I know, WIN API libraries aren't available on the Mac?